# .NET MVC3 Can't upload large files via FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-ec2

I need a way to upload large files (50+ MB) in my .net mvc3 website (hosted on Amazon). After trying to upload a large zip file (36.9MB) FireFox shows "The connection was reset" screen and FireBug shows "Aborted" under status.

Any ideas on how I could solve it?

**Controller:**

```
private void SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
{
    using (var file = System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath("/uploads/" + uploadedFile.FileName))
        uploadedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(file);
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="56320" executionTimeout="1500"/>
</system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength= "10485760"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [maxAllowedContentLength](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits) property is in bytes:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength= "10485760"/>
```

10485760 bytes = 10MB. So if you try to upload a file that is larger than 10MB you will fail.

Be consistent between your [`maxRequestLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) which is in KB:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- Limit file uploads to 55MB -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="56320" executionTimeout="1500"/>
</system.web>
```

which indicates a limit of 55MB and your `requestLimits`. Like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- Limit file uploads to 55MB -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="57671680"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I did it as u said. But it still uploads files under 1-2 Mb only. Do u know if there are any other settings I have to check? Could give any suggestions please?